# Div does not infer max width from css-grid parent, ellipsis never happens

Tags: reactjs, css, css-grid, ellipsis

I have a grid layout with `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr`. Each column contains a div with text in it. I would like my text to show ellipsis when it becomes too big to fit the column. The number of columns will be random.

I tried to go with the following css for my div containing text:

```
.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

But unless I specify a width it will not show ellipsis.

My css file:

```css
.top-container {
  width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.column-container-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.column-container-3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

My html:

```html
<div>
   <div className="top-container">
       <div style={{background: "grey"}}>first column</div>
       <div style={{background: "yellow"}}>second column</div>
     </div>
     <div className="top-container">
       <div className="column-container-2">
          <div style={{gridColumnStart: 1, background: "blue"}}>
              <div className="truncate">This is my long text</div>
           </div>
           <div style={{gridColumnStart: 2, background: "red"}}>
              <div className="truncate">This is another long text</div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div className="column-container-3">
           <div style={{gridColumnStart: 1, background: "green"}}>
               <div className="truncate">This is another long text</div>
           </div>
           <div style={{gridColumnStart: 2, background: "purple"}}>
              <div className="truncate">This is another long text</div>
           </div>
           <div style={{gridColumnStart: 3, background: "black"}}>
              <div className="truncate">This is another long text</div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

You can see the code on Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rtrhv3

I would expect my

```html
<div className="column-container-3">
           <div style={{gridColumnStart: 1, background: "green"}}>
               <div className="truncate">This is another long text</div>
           </div>
           <div style={{gridColumnStart: 2, background: "purple"}}>
              <div className="truncate">This is another long text</div>
           </div>
           <div style={{gridColumnStart: 3, background: "black"}}>
              <div className="truncate">This is another long text</div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

to be the same size as `<div style={{background: "grey"}}>first column</div>` and split his width evenly between his 3 columns. The text insides the columns should be truncated with ellipsis in order to fit the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nesting it too much:

- remove the `top-container` wrapper for the second row,
- now because the default `min-width` or `min-height` for *grid items* are `auto`, you don't see the *ellipsis* - reset this using `min-width: 0` for *all grid items*, and
- `gridColumnStart` *inline* definitions also not needed here.

See demo below and [**`updated stackblitz`**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-s3nsoa?file=index.js):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="container">
          <div style={{background: "grey"}}>first column</div>
          <div style={{background: "yellow"}}>second column</div>
          <div className="column-container-2">
            <div style={{background: "blue"}}>
              <div className="truncate">This is my long text</div>
            </div>
            <div style={{background: "red"}}>
              <div className="truncate">This is another long text</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="column-container-3">
            <div style={{background: "green"}}>
              <div className="truncate">This is another long text</div>
            </div>
            <div style={{background: "purple"}}>
              <div className="truncate">This is another long text</div>
            </div>
            <div style={{background: "black"}}>
              <div className="truncate">This is another long text</div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 400px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; /* added */
}

.column-container-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.column-container-3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.column-container-2 > div,
.column-container-3 > div {
  min-width: 0; /* added */
}

.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I would have never guessed the min-width issue, thanks a lot kind stranger!